# Runnning a python script on a socket with ncat?

Tags: networking, command-line, python

I want to make a python script run on a socket of server in LAN. I wrote a number guessing script and i want to make it run on socket for other clients to play with it by connecting to port (say 1234). I know to achieve this by socket programming from python. But this question is to ask as to why this fails?

`ncat 192.168.0.108 -lvp 1234 -e /usr/bin/python3.5 number_game.py`

the script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.5
import random
num=random.randint(1,20)
flag=0
print("Welcome to the game...")
for i in range(1,7):
    print("Take a guess")
    guess=int(input())
    if guess > num:
        print("Way too high")
    else:
        if guess < num:
            print("Way too low")
        else:
            flag=1
            break;
if flag == 1:
    print("You made it in "+str(i)+" attempts")
else:
    print("better luck next time")
```

the error:

`Ncat: Version 7.31 ( https://nmap.org/ncat )
Ncat: Got more than one port specification: 1234 number_game.py. QUITTING.`

Comment: The manpage says: `ncat [OPTIONS...] [hostname] [port]`. You should surround your command with quotes: `-e '/usr/bin/python3.5 number_game.py'`, as otherwise `number_game.py` is inerpreted as port number (see the error message).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution

You are trying to listen on the port `1234`, and to connect to machine with the IP `192.168.1.108` in the same time.

You can't do that, you either listen for the connection using this :

```
ncat -lvp 1234 -e "/usr/bin/python3.5 number_game.py"`
```

or you initiate the connection to the desired machine using this :

```
ncat -v -e "/usr/bin/python3.5 number_game.py" 192.168.0.108 1234
```

## Note

When you use `ncat` (or `nc`) to initiate the connection, you have to keep the `IP` (or `hostname`) and the `port` the last parameters.

Look to the synopsis of `ncat` in the manual : `ncat [OPTIONS...] [hostname] [port]`